# Displaying arrays from different methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this code.

In the third method I am asked to display what was typed in by the user in the method enterSequenceNames and enterSequenceLength

I'm struggling, as these are in 2 different methods, and also they are array? Please, how do I go about this. Here is my code so far.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class P12Ex5
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size;

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of sequences in the film: ");
    size = sc.nextInt();
    int option;

    int [] numberOfSequences;
    //String [] name;
    //int [] length;


    numberOfSequences = new int [size];
    //name = new String [size];
    //length = new int [size];


    do
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*************** MENU ***************"); 
        System.out.println("1.       Enter sequene names"); 
        System.out.println("2.       Enter the length of each sequence in the film(in minutes)");
        System.out.println("3.       Display all sequence details (names and length"); 
        System.out.println("4.       Display the details of longest sequence"); 
        System.out.println("5.       Display the name of the shortest sequence"); 
        System.out.println("6.       Calculate and display the average sequence length"); 
        System.out.println("7.       Exit system"); 

        System.out.println(); 
        System.out.print("Please enter an option: ");
        option = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
            enterSequenceNames(numberOfSequences);
            break;

            case 2:
            enterSequenceLength(numberOfSequences);
            break;

            //case 3:
            //displayFilmDetails(numberOfSequences, name, length);



        }

    }while(option != 0);

}   
private static void enterSequenceNames(int [] numberOfSequencesIn)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i;

    String name;


    for(i=0; i<numberOfSequencesIn.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter name of sequence "+(i+1)+": ");
        name = sc.next();

    }
}

private static void enterSequenceLength(int [] numberOfSequencesIn)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i;
    int length;

    for(i=0; i<numberOfSequencesIn.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter the length of sequence "+(i+1)+": ");
        length = sc.nextInt(); 

    }


}

private static void displayFilmDetails(int [] numberOfSequencesIn, String [] nameIn, int [] lengthIn)
{
    System.out.println();



    for( int i = 0; i<numberOfSequencesIn.length; i++)
    {
      // System.out.println("Name:    "+nameIn[i]+"Length:      "+lengthIn[i]);
     // System.out.print(nameIn[i], lengthIn[i]);


     }                           
 }
}
```

Comment: You can set them as global array and than dispaly/call in your reuire mrthod

Answer (score 0):

Define the array outside of the method, that way you can access it throughout the class.  Setting it to `static` will let you access it throughout your program as well.